# String создался в пуле несмотря на конкатенацию?

Tags: java, строки

Я понимаю почему работает этот код. в строке 1 создание объекта в пуле, в строке 2 конкатенация, после конкатенации на ссылке t1 сидит новый объект,

```
String t1 = "a";
t1 += "b";
String t2 = "ab";
System.out.println(t1 == t2); //false
```

Но я не могу понять это:

```
String s1 = "a" + "b";
String s2 = "ab";
System.out.println(s1 == s2); //true
```

Почему строка `s1` создалась в пуле несмотря на конкатенацию?

Comment: На SO пишут, что ява умеет такое, хотя это фича, которая *не обязана* работать: http://stackoverflow.com/a/767655/2908793

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вероятно, потому что это конкатенация литералов, которая вычисляется на этапе компиляции. Строка `String s1 = "a" + "b";` при компиляции сворачивается до `String s1 = "ab";`, поэтому `s1 == s2`. Если же в конкатенации будут участвовать не литералы, а переменные, то такого не случится:

```
String s1 = "a";
String s2 = s1 + "b";
String s3 = "ab";

System.out.println(s2 == s3); //false
```

Answer (score 5):

В данной ситуации логичный вывод состоит в том что во втором случае никакой конкатенации не происходило. Компилятор видимо понял что тут 2 константы и соединил их в одну строку.

Comment: Именно так и происходит.